# Can a Trailblazer concept inherit from another and be able to extend its operations (multiple inheritance)?

Tags: trailblazer

Consider an abstract `Tag` concept where there are different kinds of tags, say `Topic` and `Location` (amongst others), that are unrelated apart from being tags. They have the same base `Tag` properties in common but are otherwise different.

A `Topic` concept is based on a similar `Tag` concept. An operation like `Topic::Update` would usually inherit from `Topic::Create`, but such an operation also needs to inherit from `Tag::Update`. Ruby doesn't support multiple inheritance - can Trailblazer support this?

- Trailblazer operations support inheritance through a `builds` block that allows them to instantiate a subclass based on the contents of the supplied `params` hash. This works where the base class (`Tag`) is public-facing and operations are invoked through the base class. However, in this example, the public-facing class is the `Topic` subclass.
- Operations need to be invoked through the subclass (`Topic`) but have its operations be based off a common `Tag` base class (a *reverse builder* ?).

Here is one way that this can be achieved through single inheritance (but it illustrates the shortcomings of this approach)...

Each type of tag is stored in its own database table and has ActiveRecord classes like this:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base 
  self.abstract_class = true
end
class Topic < Tag; end
```

The Trailblazer concept would follow a similar design - a `Tag` operation would provide the base functionality and be subclassed by more a specific operation (`Topic`). The `Tag` operation would not be used directly - a `Topic` controller, for example, would use the `Topic` operation.

The `Topic` operation inherits from `Tag` but must specify its own `Topic` model which seems to be only possible within each operation, requiring each to be subclassed explicitly:

```
class Topic < Tag 
  class Create < Tag::Create
    model Topic
  end 
  class Update < Tag::Update
    model Topic
  end 
  class Delete < Tag::Delete
    model Topic
  end 
end
```

A problem with this is that the contract, being defined on the base operation, thinks that it is a `Tag` rather than a `Topic` and this leads to issues where it's used as a model. An example showing where this is a problem is in a cell's view: the `Topic` concept has a cell that presents views to manipulate its objects. It renders forms using `simple_form_for`, like this:

```
simple_form_for operation.contract
```

This doesn't work as expected because the contract thinks it is a `Tag` and this breaks the form:

- its parameters are sent as `params[:tag]` instead of `params[:topic]`
- the submit button's label is *Create Tag* instead of *Create Topic*.

The cell can't use `operation.model` (which would otherwise work) because it won't see any form errors when rendering after a submited operation fails.

A way to solve this is to be explicit with `simple_form_for`:

```
simple_form_for operation.contract, as: :topic, url: topics_path ...
```

Another problem occurs when adding properties to `Topic`, because this requires extending the `Tag` contract. The usual way to do this is to add a `contract do..end` block to the `Topic::Create` operation. The problem occurs because such a block would not be seen by `Topic::Update` and `Topic::Delete` because they inherit from their `Tag` counterparts and not from `Topic::Create`.

An alternative would be for a subclassed `Topic::Update` operation to inherit from `Topic::Create`. This would remove the need to specify the model (because `Topic::Create` does it) but would mean that anything added by the `Tag::Update` operation would be lost:

```
class Update < Create
  action :update
end
```

The `action` needs to be respecified because `Tag::Update` isn't inherited but, because `Topic::Create` is inherited, properties added in `Topic::Create` are available in `Topic::Update`.

Both of these styles work as long as changes are only in one base class. It breaks whe there are changes in both because Ruby does not support multiple inheritance. Consider the `Delete` operation which usually looks like this:

```
class Delete < Create
  action :find
  def process(params)
    # validate params and then delete
  end
end
```

If that is `Tag::Delete` then `Topic::Delete` could be either

```
  class Delete < Tag::Delete
    model Topic
  end
```

or

```
class Delete < Create
  action :find
end
```

In the former case `Topic::Delete` would be unaware of properties added by `Topic::Create` and, in the latter case, `Topic::Delete` would lacks the `process` method defned in `Tag::Delete`.

**How can a Trailblazer concept inherit another and be able to extend its operations ?**

Answer (score 1):

**The effect of multiple inheritance can be achieved by using modules.**

First define the ActiveRecord objects like this:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

There is no longer a base `Tag` abstract class, allowing `Tag` to be defined as a module like this  (`app/concepts/tag/crud.rb`):

```
module Tag
  module Create
    def self.included(base)
      base.send :include, Trailblazer::Operation::Model
      base.send :model, base.parent # e.g. Thing::Tag => Thing
      base.send :contract, Form
    end

    class Form < Reform::Form
      property ...
    end

    def process(params)
      ...
    end
  end
  module Update
    def self.included(base)
      base.send :action, :update
    end
  end
  module Delete
    def self.included(base)
      base.send :action, :find
    end
    def process(params)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Code that would normally be placed inside operation classes (such as `include Model` and `contract`) are placed inside a `self.included` method so that they are executed within the scope of the including class. The ruby `send` method needs to be used to invoke such methods on the including class from within the module's `self.included` method.

Using this `Tag` module, a `Topic` tag would look like this (`app/concepts/tag/topic/crud.rb`)

```
class Topic
  class Create < Trailblazer::Operation
    include Tag::Create
    contract do
      property ...
    end
  end
  class Update < Create
    include Tag::Update
  end
  class Delete < Create
    include Tag::Delete
    def process(params)
      ....
      super
    end
  end
end
```

This allows extension of the `Tag` contract by `Topic::Create`, which adds properties to the contract, and further customisation of `Tag` methods like the `Delete::process` example that calls `super` to invoke `Tag::Delete::process`. Aditionally, the contract will know it's a `Topic` so things like `simple_form` will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Using a module to share common data is one (correct) way of inheriting.

However, you shouldn't forget that you can also use Trailblazer's **compositional interface**, where you could use inheritance across operation classes to inherit generic logic, and then refer to the layer objects using composition.

```
module Location
  class Create < Tag::Create       # inheritance.
    contract Tag::Contract::Create # compositional API. 
  end
end
```

The compositional interface allows you to reference a separate class and is explained [in the 2.0 docs](http://trailblazer.to/gems/operation/2.0/representer.html#composable-interface). It works for policies, contracts, representers and callback objects.